# How to enforce the 'override' keyword?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, overriding

Is there any way to enforce the usage of the C++11 `override` keyword in Visual C++ 2012?

(i.e. if I forget to say `override`, then I want to get a warning/error.)

Comment: To answer your question concretely, no, VC++ 2012 RTM contains no such warning (even disabled by default).

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks, that's the kind of answer I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C++11 almost had what you want.

Originally the `override` keyword was part of a larger proposal ([N2928](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2928.htm)) which also included the ability to enforce its usage:

```
class A
{
  virtual void f();
};

class B [[base_check]] : public A
{
    void f();  // error!
};

class C [[base_check]] : public A
{
  void f [[override]] ();  // OK
};
```

The `base_check` attribute would make it an error to override a virtual function without using the `override` keyword.

There was also a `hiding` attribute which says a function hides functions in the base class. If `base_check` is used and a function hides one from the base class without using `hiding` it's an error.

But most of the proposal was dropped and only the `final` and `override` features were kept, as "identifiers with special meaning" rather than attributes.

Comment: Is this proposal being considered again for a future revision of the standard?

Comment: @Xeo: If nobody is lobbying for it, it won't be looked at. I'd personally just put it into achecker, e.g., based on clang and make checking mandatory.

Comment: Doesn't *quite* answer the question (since although it's not in C++11, Visual C++ might still have some sort of warning I'm not aware of), but still good info, thanks. +1

Comment: ah too bad, this would be very helpful for refactoring!

Comment: @BenVoigt, should have been `A`, it was based on the second example in N2928. Fixed now.

Comment: clang 3.6 has -Winconsistent-missing-override, It already helped me catch situations where some functions were using override, but others were missing. Not as good as what you asked, but it's the best you have out-of-the-box in todays compilers.

Comment: gcc 5.0 has -Wsuggest-override, which is exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @mic_e: You should put that as an answer. Maybe as `-Werror=suggest-override`.

Answer (score 16):

There are few ways to do this in VC++ and equivalent ways with GCC as well.

**VC++**

Below are the relevant warning numbers in VC++ using Code Quality [CppCoreCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers?view=msvc-160):

```
[C26435][2] : “Function should specify exactly one of ‘virtual’, ‘override’, or ‘final’.”
[C26433][1] : “Function should be marked with override”
```

To enable these two warnings:

1. Open the `Property Pages` dialog for your project.
2. Select the `Configuration Properties` > `Code Analysis` property page.
3. Set the `Enable Code Analysis` on `Build` and `Enable Microsoft Code Analysis` properties.
4. Select the `Configuration Properties` > `Code Analysis` > `Microsoft` property page.
5. Setup the active rules (e.g.: `C++ Core Check Class Rules` contains these 2 checkers)

**GCC**

GCC 5.1+ has added new warning suggest-override that you can pass as command line option `-Wsuggest-override`.

**Clang**

Clang 3.5+ has `-Winconsistent-missing-override`, however this only detects cases if some overriding memebers or base classes use `override` but other overriding members do not. You might want to take a look at clang-tidy tool as well.

Comment: Those VC++ warnings are for _including_ override where it doesn't apply.  The question was asking for warning on a _missing_ override.

Comment: And the Clang warning also triggers if you use override on one overridden function but not another inside the same class.