# What is the MSVC equicalent of GCC's -Wsuggest-override or Clang's -Winconsistent-missing-override?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Or if there is no direct equivalent, is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enforce the 'override' keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223277/how-to-enforce-the-override-keyword)

Comment: [make usage of the c++ override keyword mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21063922/995714), [Add a warning if override keyword is not used in derived class](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/396484/add-a-warning-if-override-keyword-is-not-used-in-d.html)

Comment: sadly no, i read them previously, but they don't help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223277/ this question is good, but the answers are for different problems. Since it's a 8 year old question i was hoping to get a solution for MSVC, since clang and GCC has gotten the right features since then.

Comment: I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: @BarrnetChou see my comment above, that has been posted to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/396484/add-a-warning-if-override-keyword-is-not-used-in-d.html long time ago