# Requiring virtual function overrides to use override keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, overriding, virtual

C++11 added `override` to ensure that member functions you write that you intend to override base-class virtual functions actually do (or won't compile).

But in a large object hierarchy, sometimes you could accidentally end up writing a member function that overrides a base-class virtual when you didn't intend it! For instance:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() { }  // because obviously every class has foo().
};

struct B : A { ... };

class C : B {
private:
    void foo() {
        // was intended to be a private function local to C
        // not intended to override A::foo(), but now does
    }
};
```

Is there some compiler flag/extension that would at least issue a warning on `C::foo` ? For readability and correctness, I just would like to enforce that all overrides use `override`.

Comment: In reality, your function will be named `GazimpleWidget(Widget& w)` and obviously `C::GazimpleWidget(Widget& w)` still gazimples widgets. You only get such problems when you try to abbreviate `C::GazimpleWidget( )` to `C::GW( )`. Don't do that.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223277/how-to-enforce-the-override-keyword

Comment: @MSalters I do not understand the comment.

Comment: @Barry: The problem with your simplified example is that `foo` is misleading. Real functions with real names are far less likely to collide unintentionally. If they are named the same, they should be doing the same and then overriding is probably not an error.

Comment: @MSalters "less likely...", "should be...", "probably not...". Yes, obviously. The entire point of the question is that the unlikely case happened, the function was incorrectly implemented, and I would like to verify this at compile-time.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Looks like the GCC 5.1 release added exactly the [warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-Wsuggest-override) I was looking for:

> `-Wsuggest-override`
>        Warn about overriding virtual functions that are not marked with the override keyword.

Compiling with `-Wsuggest-override` `-Werror=suggest-override` would then enforce that all overrides use `override`.

Comment: They removed this option from their docs for GCC 10.3 and later versions. The option still works on those versions though.

Comment: @VainMan Half the warnings are in [Dialect Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-Wsuggest-override) for some reason, it's very confusing.

Answer (score 14):

There are two things you can do.

First, Clang 3.5 and higher have a `-Winconsistent-missing-override` warning (triggered by `-Wall`). This does not quite work for your example, but only if you would add a `void foo() override {}` to `class B` and not in `class C`. What you actually want is `-Wmissing-override`, to locate all missing `override`, not just the inconsistently missing ones. That is currently not provided, but you might complain on the Clang mailinglist and they might add it.

Second, you use [**Howard Hinnant's trick**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514026/819272) to *temporarily* add `final` to the base class member function and recompile. The compiler will then locate all further derived classes that attempt to override the `virtual` base member function. You can then fix the missing ones. It's a bit more work and requires frequent rechecking when your class hierarchy expands.

Answer (score 9):

The problem I see with `-Werror=suggest-override` is that it does not allow you to write the following:

```
void f() final {...}
```

Even though there is an implicit `override` here. The `-Werror=suggest-override` does not ignore this (like it should, since the `override` is redundant in this case)

But it is more complicated than that... If you write

```
virtual void f() final {...}
```

It means a completely different thing than

```
virtual void f() override final {...}
```

The first case does not need to override anything! The second does.

So I am assuming the GCC check is implemented this way (i.e. to sometimes accept the redundant `override`) in order to get the last case right. But this does not play well e.g. with clang-tidy, which will correctly remove the override when final is sufficient (but then GCC compilation will fail...)

Comment: I agree with you.  However, if we follow the advice to only use the "virtual" keyword on functions  when first _introducing_ a new virtual function, the issue you show where a final function may-or-may-not-override goes away.  (This disallows code that introduces a virtual function and implements it as final, which seems nonsensical anyway.)  Then the meaning is clear:  "virtual" = new non-overriding virtual function, while "override" or "final" both indicate they are overrides (and do NOT have "virtual") and both should satisfy the g++ warning (but unfortunately doesn't.)

Comment: Declaring and finalising a base virtual function in the same breath, thus defeating the point of it being virtual, seems totally pointless. I'd almost say the language should disallow this, then compilers wouldn't have to ponder the philosophy of it.

Comment: I agree with @underscore_d and Scott Meyers on this one.  If there is only one way to implement f(), take a firm stand and declare it non-virtual.

Answer (score 0):

GCC and Clang are covered by other answers. Here's same for VC++ from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41109550/207661):

Below are the relevant warning numbers in VC++:

```
C4263 (level 4) 'function': member function does not override any base class virtual member function
C4266 (level 4) 'function': no override available for virtual member function from base 'type'; function is hidden
```

To enable these two warnings, you can use one of following options:

1. Set warning level to 4 in project settings and then disable the warnings you don't want. This is my prefered way. To disable unwanted Level 4 warnings, go to project settings > C/C++ > Advanced and then enter warning numbers in Disable Specific Warnings box.
2. Enable above two warnings using code.

   ```
   #pragma warning(default:4263)
   #pragma warning(default:4266)
   ```
3. Enable above two warnings in project settings > C/C++ > Command Line and then enter /w34263 /w34266.  Here /wNxxxx option means enable xxxx warnings in Level N (N = 3 is default level). You can also do /wdNxxxx which disables the xxxx warning in level N.

Comment: The question was about how to enable a compiler warning when an the "override" keyword was not used on an overridden method, not how to enbale warnings on missusage of the override keyword.

Comment: Note: I wouldn't recommend adding those to the Command Line section of Project Settings. There is a section specifically for warnings; it would make more sense to put them there.